# Unable to push to Facebook custom audience with sandbox ad account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

We are looking to test pushing custom audiences to the Marketing API.

Below is the code used for the push with credentials omitted:

```
access_token = ''
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)

my_account = AdAccount('act_token')
custom_audience = my_account.get_custom_audiences()
print(custom_audience)

fields = []
params = {
    'name': 'My new Custom Audience',
    'subtype': 'CUSTOM',
    'description': 'People who purchased on my website',
    'customer_file_source': 'USER_PROVIDED_ONLY'
}
custom_audience = CustomAudience().api_create(
    parent_id='act_token',
    fields=fields,
    params=params,
)

# Add users to the Custom Audience
hashed_emails = ['9b431636bd164765d63c573c346708846af4f68fe3701a77a3bdd7e7e5166254', '8cc62c145cd0c6dc444168eaeb1b61b351f9b1809a579cc9b4c9e9d7213a39ee']
hashed_phone_numbers = ['4eaf70b1f7a797962b9d2a533f122c8039012b31e0a52b34a426729319cb792a', '98df8d46f118f8bef552b0ec0a3d729466a912577830212a844b73960777ac56']
custom_audience.add_users(CustomAudience.Schema.email_hash, hashed_emails)
custom_audience.add_users(CustomAudience.Schema.phone_hash, hashed_phone_numbers)
```

We tried three methods to test pushing a custom audience:

1. We tried following [Facebook's instructions to create a sandbox ad account](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2023/06/21/marketing-api-sandbox-capability-now-re-enabled/) and tried to push and audience to this account.  We got an error like: "your admin needs to add this ad account to business."  We tried adding the sandbox ad account via the business account UI but ran into an error "You need to be assigned access to this account before requesting to claim it into a Meta Business Account." This is odd because we believe we used the same facebook account for creating the sandbox ad account and the business account.
2. We tried adding the sandbox ad account to another business account.  We didn't run into the error message in (1) but we got stuck with an error saying "You're request to gain access to this ad account hasn't been approved yet."  We went into the settings for the sandbox ad account and did not see an option to approve this request
3. We created a real Facebook Ad account, linked it to the business account, but when we pushed we got the error "Customer List Audiences Are Not Available: Ad accounts owned by businesses new to Facebook products can create customer file Custom Audiences after several weeks of following our policies."  We waited several weeks and the problem persisted

We made sure to accept the terms of service for the ad accounts.

We are unsure of how to proceed with our integration.  We have been unable to contact Facebook support.

Comment: FB's Sandbox Ad Accounts are very limited in uses. FB doesn't say that anywhere. But, its practically useless when you venture outside of creating simple ads. 

I would recommend creating a real ad account in your test BM and use that instead.

Comment: thanks that's helpful to hear @Seeni. we got an error that never went away when trying to use a real FB Ad account "Customer List Audiences Are Not Available: Ad accounts owned by businesses new to Facebook products can create customer file Custom Audiences after several weeks of following our policies."  We have been unable to reach Facebook support.  Any thoughts on what we can do?